# In Windows OS why is a single line without any newline character is being displayed in two lines in notepad?

Tags: windows, newline

I'm just trying to understand the below scenario.

I'm entering some data to notepad without any new line character but it is being displayed in two lines as shown in below (but I want output in single line only).

[image: image of notepad with some data]

Is Windows OS adding a newline character to the data after a certain limit ? What is the reason behind displaying it in two lines ?

It might look funny, but please help me understand.

Comment: The word wrap option

Comment: @Ross Word wrap is off

Answer (score 2):

Notepad is not adding a newline character to the data. Notepad has a limit on how many characters it will display on a single line, even with the word-wrap mode turned off. This does not effect the actual characters in the file.